# Django PasswordResetForm not working when extending it

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication

I wanted to make some changes to the default

django.contrib.auth.forms.PasswordResetForm

I did the following:

```
class CustomPasswordResetForm(PasswordResetForm):
    def is_valid(self):
        ret = forms.Form.is_valid(self)
        for f in self.errors:
            self.fields[f].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'invalid'})
        return ret
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        if not User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('כתובת אימייל זאת לא קיימת במערכת!')
```

nothing to complicated, just added a class for invalid fields and added an error if the email doesn't exist (not sure why this doesn't happen by default tbh)

Also I defined the new form in urls.py

```
url(r'^password_reset/$', auth_views.password_reset,{'password_reset_form': CustomPasswordResetForm,}, name='password_reset'),
```

both the functions I overrided are working as intended, but the reset password form no longer works, I'm not receiving an email, even though the form passes with no validation errors on to /password_reset/done/

Comment: here you are not returning email. return self.cleaned_data['email'] in clean_email function

Comment: Thats not whats causing it, I just checked and even if the class is empty with just "pass" the form dosen't send a reset email. the only way to get it working is to delete {'password_reset_form': CustomPasswordResetForm,} from the urls and return to the original form

Comment: @GeoJacob is correct, you need to add `return email` to your `get_email` function. That might not be enough to fix the problem, but it's definitely not going to work until you do it.